# How to sort rows with specific keywords

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Question is quit complicated than titled subject, basically i have a list of people names, not actaul name, like mom, dad, sis, sister, and list goes on, in short i have a contact list of phone book, i want filter some name from it, like mom, dad, sis, sister, bro, brother and this list have about 60+ keywords, when we want look for same in contact list, i need to find each word from excel, and its very much time consuming, i want to know about a formula, where i can put these keywords, and result should come out as per the required data. hope question much understandable, need expert advise on same.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` probably does the trick. If using Office 365 `XLOOKUP` would be better. If you have an older Excel version and the result column is backwards from the search value, look into `INDEX/MATCH`

Comment: " i want to know about a formula, where i can put these keywords," >> use Advanced Filter to make a list of UniqueItems (record and assign to macro for repetitive tasks) then Data Validation for a list to select from them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.